# Ruby Hash declaration with an inline block in the middle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, block

Here is an XML document:

```
<Request>
    <Field1>value1</Field1>
    <Field2>value2</Field2>
    <Section1>
        <Field attribute1="attrval1">value11</Field>
        <Field attribute1="attrval2">value12</Field>
        <Field attribute1="attrval3">value13</Field>
        <Field attribute1="attrval4">value14</Field>
    </Section1>
    <Section2>
        <Fld1>value21</Fld1>
        <Fld2>value22</Fld2>
        <Fld3>value23</Fld3>
    </Section2>
</Request>
```

which is parsed by following Ruby code:

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML(request.raw_post)
req = xml.xpath('/Request')
hash = {
    field1: req.xpath('Field1').text,
    field2: req.xpath('Field2').text,
    section1: req.xpath('Section1/Field').map {|fld|
        {
            attribute1: fld.attr('attribute1'),
            value: fld.text
        }
    },
    section2: req.xpath('Section2').some_method { |sec2|
        {
            fld1: sec2.xpath('Fld1').text,
            fld2: sec2.xpath('Fld2').text,
            fld3: sec2.xpath('Fld3').text
        }
    }
}
```

Parsing of Section1 is a real working piece of code.

Parsing of non-repeated values in Section2 is a concept - something I would like to see to not have to declare

```
sec2 = req.xpath('Section2')
```

before hash declaration.

I would like to see some inline block.

Any suggestions?

Comment: just as variant for parsing simple `XML` you could try `Hash.from_xml`

Comment: @IS04: Will it parse attributes?

Comment: you could look http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/from_xml/class

Comment: @IS04: Ok, it won't.

Answer (score 1):

Not answer, but as alternative you could try:

```
ActiveSupport::XmlMini.parse(xml)


{"Request"=>
  {"Field1"=>{"__content__"=>"value1"},
   "Field2"=>{"__content__"=>"value2"},
   "Section1"=>
    {"Field"=>
      [{"attribute1"=>"attrval1", "__content__"=>"value11"},
       {"attribute1"=>"attrval2", "__content__"=>"value12"},
       {"attribute1"=>"attrval3", "__content__"=>"value13"},
       {"attribute1"=>"attrval4", "__content__"=>"value14"}]},
   "Section2"=>
    {"Fld1"=>{"__content__"=>"value21"},
     "Fld2"=>{"__content__"=>"value22"},
     "Fld3"=>{"__content__"=>"value23"}}}}
```

Comment: Thank you for an useful reply. I hope this will come in handy some day. For now this solution is unacceptable as I want actually to get an object to be able to query it like: `obj.Section2.Fld1`. Hash is an intermediate step before `Hashie::Mash.new`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `map` here, too:

```
req.xpath('Section2/*').map { |f| [f.name.downcase.to_sym, f.text] }.to_h
# => {:fld1=>"value21", :fld2=>"value22", :fld3=>"value23"}
```

Comment: Doesn't map make an array?

Comment: yes, and [`Array#to_h`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-to_h) converts it to a hash

Comment: I like the solution with `instance_eval` more. It doesn't require additional conversions.