# Ruby block's result as an argument

Tags: ruby, block, inline

There are many examples how to pass Ruby block as an argument, but these solutions pass the block itself.

I need a solution that takes some variable, executes an inline code block passing this variable as a parameter for the block, and the return value as an argument to the calling method. Something like:

```
a = 555
b = a.some_method { |value|
    #Do some stuff with value
    return result
}
```

or

```
a = 555
b = some_method(a) { |value|
    #Do some stuff with value
    return result
}
```

I could imagine a custom function:

```
class Object
   def some_method(&block)
      block.call(self)
   end
end
```

or

```
def some_method(arg, &block)
   block.call(arg)
end
```

but are there standard means present?

Comment: Are you talking about [`#tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-tap) ?

Comment: @Arup Rakshit: `a=555.tap{|val| val/5}` results in 555 while I am expecting 111

Comment: This is the expected behavior, `tap` returns the receiver, not the block's result.

Comment: Yes.. Then you need [`#instance_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval) `a = 55; a.instance_eval { |o| o/5 } # => 11` .. Not `#tap`.

Comment: @Paul could you post a "real" example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Arup Rakshit: Please post this as an answer here.

Comment: @Stefan: You can find it there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905884/ruby-hash-declaration-with-an-inline-block-in-the-middle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you are looking for [`instance_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval).

> Evaluates a string containing Ruby source code, or the given block, within the context of the receiver (`obj`). In order to set the context, the variable self is set to obj while the code is executing, giving the code access to `obj’s` instance variables. In the version of `instance_eval` that takes a `String`, the optional second and third parameters supply a filename and starting line number that are used when reporting compilation errors.

```
a = 55
a.instance_eval do |obj|
  # some operation on the object and stored it to the
  # variable and then returned it back
  result = obj / 5 # last stament, and value of this expression will be
                  # returned which is 11
end # => 11
```

Comment: I'm not sure if `instance_eval` is the right tool for the job. It does much more than just passing an object to the block and returning its result ...

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly how @Arup Rakshit commented. Use tap

```
def compute(x)
  x + 1
end

compute(3).tap do |val|
  logger.info(val)
end # => 4
```